# Get SRID of geometry column in exasol (ST_SRID equivalent)

Tags: sql, spatial, spatial-query, exasolution, exasol

It seems that there is no `ST_SRID` function in [`exasol`](https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/sql_references/geospatialdata/geospatialdata_overview.htm) like in other DBMS: `SELECT ST_SRID(geom) FROM sampletable`

Is there an efficient workaround to determine the SRID of a `geometry` column? So far I only had success in parsing the `COLUMN_TYPE` string from `EXA_USER_COLUMNS` of the table containing the geometry column, which seems a bit clumsy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific function for this in Exasol.

Besides using `EXA_USER_COLUMNS` you can also use [TYPEOF](https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/sql_references/functions/alphabeticallistfunctions/typeof.htm) if you are using Exasol 7.1. This is a scalar function that returns the data type of it's argument.

For example:

```sql
create or replace table t(a geometry, b geometry(1), c geometry(2));
insert into t values (null,null,null);
select regexp_substr(typeof(a), '[\d]*'), regexp_substr(typeof(b), '[\d]*'),regexp_substr(typeof(c), '[\d]*') from t;
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like a more efficient solution! Unfortunately, I only have access to exasol 7.0.X therefore it seems that I have to stick to parsing the COLUMN_TYPE of EXA_USER_COLUMNS.